# Calculate number of days between two dates with momentsjs

Tags: jquery, datetime, momentjs

I got two dates stored inside a var (created by a date picker). To format these I am using [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

I want to calculate the number of days between these two fields and store this number inside a var `days`. This is my code so far:

```
// When someone clicks my submit button, I create an url stored in the var url.
$(".book_submit").on('click', function(e){

  // I get the datepicker and input fields data
  var from = $('.from').val();
  var to = $('.to').val();

  // I can format the "from" var the way I want
  from  = moment(from, "DD.MM.YYYY");
  from = moment(from).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

  // I can format the "to" var the way I want
  to = moment(to, "DD.MM.YYYY");
  to = moment(to).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

  // I want to store the number between the two dates in the var "days", to place it inside my link below. I have found ".diff(to, 'days') in the moments documentation.

  //days = from.diff(to, 'days');   // =1

  var url = "https://mycustomlink&days= " + days + "";

});
```

I can't get `from.diff(to, 'days')` to work and store it inside a variable. I have tried to set it like:

```
var days = from.diff(to, 'days');
```

How can I store the difference between these to days inside my var `days`? I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<del>Apart from `.diff()`, you could also use *moment* `duration`s: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/</del>

***Edit***: Don't know what was I thinking back then. Thanks @aedm for pointing it out. There is no need of duration here, which is for creating time spans.

[`.diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) works as intended, just that you have to make sure you are using the correct format to parse the dates.

**Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/md4jte5d/**

**Example Snippet:**

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function(e) {
 var fromDate = $('#fromDate').val(), 
    toDate = $('#toDate').val(), 
  from, to, druation;
  
 from = moment(fromDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'); // format in which you have the date
 to = moment(toDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');     // format in which you have the date
  
 /* using diff */
 duration = to.diff(from, 'days')     
 
 /* show the result */
 $('#result').text(duration + ' days');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
From: <input id="fromDate" type='date' />
To: <input id="toDate" type='date' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="btn">Submit</button><hr />
<p id="result"></p>
```

---

As I see in your code, you have comments like this:

> ```
> // I can format the "from" var the way I want
> ```

No. You cannot format the dates the way *you* want. You have to use the format in which the date you are parsing is in. In my example, as I am using the HTML5 date, the returned date is in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, hence using that format. In your case, determine what format your textboxes return the dates in, and use that format.

You may also omit the format altogether, if you are sure that the returned date is in a standard format.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Try your fiddle with "10/01/2000" and "11/02/2000".

Comment: To make it clear, `duration.days()` is wrong, because it only gives you the days part of the difference.  However, `to.diff(from, 'days')` works as intended.

Comment: Thanks @aedm. Have corrected the answer. Don't know what was I thinking back then :/ Must've been up late night and mixed up things from elsewhere!! Thank you once again, it would have gone unnoticed if it weren't you.

Comment: Thanks for fixing. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the difference in another unit of measurement, pass that measurement as the second argument.

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

[Refer this for further](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have found this inside the documentation as well, but to be honest I even do not know how to replace the dates displayed in your example with my vars. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Here first variable is the year, second is the month and third is the date. So, you need to pass two values relatively.